# What should the confidence interval with the whole population as sample result in?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, sample-size

Given the formula for
Confidence Interval = x̄ ± z * ơ / √n

If I have a population of 3000 people.
I take a sample of 3000 (I assume I can do this without replacement, so this is the whole population)
so n = 3000

I am expecting it to result in
Confidence Interval = x̄ ± 0

Because I asked everyone in the population, I should be 100% sure of the population mean.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

The formula you give is effectively for a population of infinite size and a finite sample. In contrast, for finite sized populations (and if you ignore potential future members of the population), you would want an adjustment for the finite size of the population (see e.g. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584046/which-confidence-interval-can-i-use-to-a-report-on-a-small-survey)).

So, yes, your intuition is correct.

Comment: The stated formula would also apply for a finite population and sampling with replacement

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you sample n times with replacement from a population of size n, you definitely would not have the whole population (because of instead of everyone you got some people repeatedly). To do it also only makes sense if the response is noisy (if you just get the same answer every time, there's no benefit to asking the same population member repeatedly).

Comment: My point was that if you sample with replacement from a finite population, the $\bar x \pm z \frac s{\sqrt{n}}$ is still a confidence interval for the mean of the population, using repeated values in the calculations (you do not know whether seeing $X_i=2$ is the same person or somebody else with the same value).  Yes you are likely not to have the full population and instead have repeated values, but that is not an issue

Comment: Why would that still be a valid confidence interval? It has neither a correction for the finite size of the population, nor does it reflect that sampling the same unit again gives less (or possibly no new) information than different units.

Comment: If you sample with replacement from a finite population and ask "red or blue?" without being able to identify whether someone has previously also been sampled, that is a reasonable confidence interval